# How i can go away from closure in viewcontroller?

Tags: swift, firebase, viewcontroller

try to find some info about it, but i can't.

So i got this code when i clicking on login.

```
@IBAction func checkLogin(_ sender: UIButton) {

    let email = userEmail.text!
    let password = userPassword.text!

    if email == "" || password == "" || !email.isValidEMail {
        userEmail.shake()
        userPassword.shake()
        return
    }

    Auth.auth().signIn(withEmail: email, password: password, completion: {(user, error) in

        var collectError = ("","")

        if error != nil {
            collectError = ("Error", (error?.localizedDescription)!)
            self.alertMsg(title: collectError.0, message: collectError.1)
            return
        }

        if !(user?.isEmailVerified)! {
            collectError = ("Error", "Your account is not verified! Confirm your account from email!")
            return
        }

        print("OK, User Authentificated: \(Auth.auth().currentUser?.email)")

        // DispatchQueue.main.async { }
        //return

        self.navigationController?.popViewController(animated: true)
        //self.dismiss(animated: true, completion: nil)

    })
```

i have first view controller which gives a user a login or registration options. So i choose for example login. try to login and it returns me back to first view controller there i got verification firebase listener if user loggen in it hides first view controller but when i click to logout in profile.storyboard it immeditialy show me first login controller. and when i try to login again again nothing happens why i dont know

i understand that i need use for navigation return back function

```
self.navigationController?.popViewController(animated: true)
```

and for buttons if i want hide viewcontrol

```
self.dismiss(animated: true, completion: nil)
```

Comment: how are you loading login controller after clicking logout ?

Comment: i have 3 storyboards main.storyboard (it's loading by default) login.storyboard if user not authorized, and profile.storyboard when i click on bar button item in action i m checkin with firebase listener if user authenitifcated he goes to profile where i have logout button or im going to login storyboard you can see this on picture https://i.imgsafe.org/29/2953953e41.png and this https://i.imgsafe.org/29/2953958006.png

Comment: login.storyboard and initial view controller loads automaticaly after i click in profile.storyboard logout button. it's looks like he remembering last viewcontroller in case is login controller and dont see main.storyboard but

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So, when your root controller of the main.storyboard is loaded or will/did appear, you are trying to check the authorization, if user is not authorized, you will present the login controller, right?

In your case you need to have at least two separated navigation stacks (let's call them the main stack and the login stack)

It means that your login view controller should be presented (not pushed) when user is not authorized and dismissed (not popped) after user will be logged successfully or the reg will be canceled.

I have almost the same reg process in my project. I will try to explain it in the example code below

```
class MainController {
    override func viewDidAppear(_ animated: Bool) {
        super.viewDidAppear(animated)

        //detecting the firebase, just a custom bool var
        if !isAuthorized {
            //call the method to present login controller
            presentLoginController()
        }
    }

    func presentLoginController(){
        let segue = UIStoryboard(name: "Login", bundle: nil)

        if let loginNavigationController = segue.instantiateInitialViewController() {

            self.present(loginNavigationController, animated: true, completion: nil)
        }

    }


}
```

Now you will see the login controller. So this will make a second navigation stack (login stack). This will be a separated navigation, where the root controller is a login navigation controller (initial controller in you Login.storyboard). For any controller in this stack if you will call navigationController?.popToRootViewController it will bring you to the root controller in the login stack. Don't use self.dismiss(animated: true, completion: nil) here, likely it will break your navigation

So when user is logged in or authorization was finished or canceled, you need to show a main controller (the main stack), where you can make that check for isAuthorized again. This is how you can make it:

```
func navigateToTheRoot(){
        //this code will dismiss all modal controllers that was presented
        UIApplication.shared.keyWindow?.rootViewController?.dismiss(animated: false, completion: nil)

        //accessing to the appDelegate
        let appDelegate = UIApplication.shared.delegate as? AppDelegate

        //now this will return your app to the main controller
        if let navigationController = appDelegate?.window?.rootViewController as? UINavigationController {
            navigationController.popToRootViewController(animated: true)
        }
 }
```

Call this method in any controller that is presented in separated navigation stack (like to cancel the registration, call this after clicking the "X" button in your login stack).

If your profile controller has a navigation controller as an initial of the Profile.storyboard (third stack - the profile stack), then you need to present it in the same way as I've used for the login controller. In this case, to make the logout, you need to call method navigateToTheRoot() from any controller in the profile stack to show the main controller.

Otherwise, if your profile controller is just a single controller without additional navigation and it was pushed from any other controller from your main stack, then you just need to call this:

```
self.navigationController?.popToRootViewController(animated: true)
```

You will see the root controller of your main.stack

Short rules to get to the root in the Main.storyboard from any other controller no matter how many controllers had been presented or pushed before:

- if you controller is presented (not in the main stack) and it is in an additional navigation stack, use navigateToTheRoot() method I've described
- if your controller was pushed (push segues or navigationController?.pushViewController for programmatically usage) use navigationController?.popToRootViewController
- if your controller is presented (is Modal) and it is just single controller without a navigation, just call self.dismiss(animated: true, completion: nil)

Hope it will help you. You can ask me if you need

P.S. In your registration controller (showing when user clicks "Зарегистрироваться") there is a small mistake "Зарег**е**стрироваться". Удачи! ;)

Comment: how i understand in first code it's all about memory, it depending how controller is loaded and keeps in memory ???

Comment: can i give you my project, as this is english stackoverflow can't speak russian

Comment: Not about memory, but the navigation stack (there is an array of view controllers in each navigation controller ). Sure, share your project, I will check it